# std::istringstream >> to double weird behaviour

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, clang, clang++

The following code prints **0** on mac osx with clang. Everywhere else it prints **5** ([clang](https://ideone.com/mVgpzS), [gcc](https://ideone.com/oZ0hy6))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss("5C3");

    double n;
    iss >> n;

    std::cout << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

When I use `int` it prints 5 as expected..

How does [operator>> of std::istringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) work and why this is happening? Is there a way to make it work in a consistent manner? (that is extract 5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant part of the standard is `[istream.formatted.arithmetic]`. The extractor behavior depends on the locale's `num_get<>` object.

There is a bug in the libc++ `num_get::do_get` function for `double`, described [in this bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17782). On other platforms, you are likely using libstdc++, which gives the behavior you expect.